# SWITCH True Multiple column and criteria in Power BI

Tags: search, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a two different columns are one is name and another one is ID.
The Name column contain text and number and the length of characters not always same.

ID column contain number only.

1.If ID column contain 38 and Name column contain "-" then Train.

2.If ID column contain 56 and Name column contain "-" then Air.

3.If ID column contain 38 and Name column does not contain "-" then Road.

4.If ID column contain 56 and Name column does not contain "-" then Road.

In Excel I am applying the following formula

```
=IF(A3="","",IFERROR(IF(REPLACE(A3,1,SEARCH("-",A3),)+0,IF(B3&""="38","TRAIN",IF(B3&""="56","AIR","ROAD"))),"ROAD"))
```

in order to get the result.

I want calculated column.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might be implemented in DAX as a calculated column that uses the SWITCH statement

```
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    T[ID] = 38
        && SEARCH( "-", T[NAME], 1, 0 ) > 0, "Train",
    T[ID] = 56
        && SEARCH( "-", T[NAME], 1, 0 ) > 0, "Air",
    T[ID]
        IN { 38, 56 }
            && SEARCH( "-", T[NAME], 1, 0 ) = 0, "Road"
)
```

The default (no matching conditions) is to return BLANK()

Nested IFs could also be used, it is a matter of taste

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It's working well.